# json RPC Blockchain not Working

Tags: blockchain, json-rpc

I am unable to connect to the Blockchain API, here is the code:

> $rpc_host = 'rpc.blockchain.info';
> $rpc_port = '80';
>   $rpc_user = 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX';
>   $rpc_pass = 'PASSWORD';
>   require_once('jsonRPCClient.php');
>   $bc = new jsonRPCClient('http://' . $rpc_user . ':' . $rpc_pass . '@' . $rpc_host . ':' . $rpc_port);
> $balance = $bc->getbalance();

I have also tried with port 443, and I still get this error (but with https://):

> EXCEPTION: Unable to connect to http:[Link Breaker]//XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX->XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX:Password@rpc.blockchain.info:80

I've tried everything I know and I've seen some people with the same problem, but no solution. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Uhm, obvious question: is your Bitcoin server running?

Comment: Yes it is, lol :P